# for loop together with if statement in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

can someone help me with this little function ?

```
opt <- function( x, shape, scale){
  k=shape
  wpd1=0.3395
  wpd2=c()
  for(i in 1:101){
  wpd = mean((k/scale) * x^k)
  if(wpd==wpd1){wpd2=wpd}else{k=k+(i-1)/100 -0.5}
  }
  return(wpd2)
}
```

when I use `opt(rnorm(10),2,3)` I get the error :

```
Error in if (wpd == wpd1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

change `mean((k/scale) * x^k)` to `mean((k/scale) * x^k, na.rm = TRUE)` you're goign to get NaN when running `(-#)^(2/3)`

Comment: Actually, you'll get `k == 1.5` at the second iteration. This is because at the first iteration `wpd1 != wpd`, so the `else` part is executed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas same thing. the mean is still going to return NA

Comment: Yes, I know, but for a slightly different reason.

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini I think there's something wrong with what you're typing in. (-0.3382435)^(2/3) is returning NaN for me. And you shouldn't be able to get a negative value out of that since you're squaring it

Comment: @RuiBarradas I would like to do so, I want to look for a new k, which is k+/- 0.5, thats why I defined the if , else statement. I know in first iteration `wpd != wpd1` then I change the k to k-0.5 and go till k+0.5 to see wether I find a mach or not !

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini But a `negative_number^1.5` is not a real. You must revise the algorithm, maybe the formula, only then it will become a solvable coding issue.